# Javafx: How to show slider thumb when min and max values are equal?

Tags: java, javafx

The javafx Slider knob disappears when the max and min values are equal.
How to have the slider still show the thumb/knob in such a case?

Comment: May i ask why you would do such thing? A slide with an equal min and max value seems to be useless.

Comment: I have 2 sliders, one's max value depends on other slider value. At one point max becomes equal to min. I still want to show the knob in such a case

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution, but you could try the following as a workaround.

You could use a change listener to the valueProperty of your first slider to set the maxValue of your second slider accordingly (probably you have this already). To make the knob shown, I guess you need two different values for the minimum and maximum.

So as a workaround you could try if the following example is working for you.

```
    slider1.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            slider2.setMax((Double) newValue + 0.000000001);
        }
    });
```

In this example, the minimum (here: 0) equals almost the maximum (here: 0.000000001). This is not a good solution, but maybe you can use this as a workaround.